# specifying dynamic id while using <af:iterator and <af:selectbooleancheckobx

Tags: iterator, oracle-adf

i have requirement to generate boolean checkbox and give different ID to track which checkbox is clicked as below:

This doesnt add the Employeedid.

Instead of this when I am using  then it works and dynamcially id is generated.

a help in how to use iterator and selectbooleancheckbox with dynamic id generation will help.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: @Vilas, I am looking for similar solution. Did you find? Can you share it?